# How many fermions?

Tags: fermions, elementary-particles

Quick question: I just read in a PhD thesis that there are 48 fermions. I count 6 quarks + 3 leptons + 3 neutrinos times 2 for anti-particles = 24 fermions. Am I missing something?

Comment: Depends on how you count, but I guess they were counting the three colors of each quark as distinct particles.

Comment: Did the paper involve SUSY?

Comment: @Jake - This was a statement regarding the SM. I believe the extra 24 fermions is simply due to taking into account the quark color as mentioned by Javier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quarks come in 6 flavors and 3 colors, which gives us 18 unique quarks.Add 6 leptons to get total of 24 matter fermions.And double the number for antimatter to get total of 48 fermions in SM.